# How to change desktop shell to only gedit and wallpaper?

Tags: uck

I'm working with the uck tool to get customized ubuntu live image(kernel).

It can be fully customized with it, but I can not change desktop shell.

Normally, when booting with the live CD, there's no log-in session.
So what I want to do is as below.

After boot with my live cd, my applications(ex, gedit) are the only ones to auto-start along with my wallpaper with some logos.

In other words, is it possible to change desktop shell to just my application, with no desktop icons, task bar and panel?

Comment: As I understand, the wallpaper, window borders and stuff are drawn by a "desktop shell", so maybe to achieve what you need you can try some very minimalistic and configurable window manager which allows to hide/disable features you don't need

Answer (score 0):

try using enlightenment desktop it can be managed so you have nothing on screen at all exept right click menu where all apps and stuff.